# Two JPanels, requesting focus and Keyboard input

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

Learning GUIs for an assignment, and would appreciate some advice...no code, for the aforementioned reason.

I have a programme with a `JFrame`, and a single `JPanel`, that contains methods that take keyboard input using the `KeyEvent` class.

My class that extends `JPanel`, has the following in it:

```
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
```

I've since modified the programme, to include a second `JPanel` (to add a control panel to the right containing 4 `JButtons`).

The problem is that the keyboard input no longer works on the first `JPanel` when I run the programme (it did before).

The keyboard input on the right JPanel only works before the second JPanel has been added to the programme. If I remove the second JPanel, keyboard input works, when it is there it doesn't....

I realised that I had `setFocusable(true);`   and    `requestFocus();` in both panels, so I deleted it from the second panel (with the `JButtons`), but it still doesn't work. I sense it's a focus issue.....any advice?

Do I need to look at KeyBindings (don't know what this is yet, but a few similar threads suggest it)....

Comment: Use a KeyListener, or a KeyAdapter

Comment: Thanks @Hackerdarshi How is this different to a KeyEvent? Do you think it won't work without one of these?

Comment: It catches a KeyEvent.

Comment: OK,thanks. Do you mind explaining why I didn't need to do that before I added the second panel?

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell you what is wrong based on two lines of code. We have no idea what panel1 and panel2 do or what components they contain.

> My class that extends JPanel, has the following in it:

A couple of problems with that:

1. You should NOT be using the `requestFocus()` method. Read the API for that method and it will tell you the appropriate method to use.
2. Even if you do use the appropriate method, you can't use that method in the constructor of a class. Requesting focus on a component can only be done to visible components on a GUI.

> Do I need to look at KeyBindings

Yes, Swing has newer and better API's than AWT. In AWT you didn't have a choice. In Swing you should be using Key Bindings. All Swing components do use Key Bindings and Actions. One of the main reasons is you don't have the focus issue.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are sections on:

1. `How to Use Key Bindings`
2. `How to Use Actions` to get you started.

A `Key Binding` is simply the process of mapping a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`.

Also, in the future, when you ask a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @javapalava, why? What part of the key binding tutorial did you not understand. What demo code did you download and test? Did you search the for  other examples that use an InputMap and ActionMap. Any new concept takes time to learn. We are not mind readers we can't guess what you find confusing.

Comment: Check out the [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)  example that allows you to move a component around a panel using KeyBindings. It is far simpler to customize because you don't need custom methods like moveRight, moveDown. You create a single Action that is paramterized and you can move in any direction with any KeyStroke.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with "pass back and force" that the focus should move on tab keypress between those two, use a `FocusTraversalPolicy` where you define who should get focus in which order.

Comment: I mean that, when I click a JButton on the left panel, it should have the programmed effect. When I use the correct keys on the right panel, it should have the programmed effect. The keyboard input on the right panel only works before the second panel has been added to the programme. If I remove the second panel, keyboard input works, when it is there it doesn't....

Comment: Well it heavily depends on what you have in your panels and how everything should behave and react. Btw. you might want to use `requestFocusInWindow()` instead of `requestFocus()` as the JavaDoc of the latter suggests. You can also find more information about the focus system at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29

Comment: `When I use the correct keys on the right panel, it should have the programmed effect.` - which is why you should be using "Key Bindings". Key bindings work even when the component doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button, that button receives the keyboard focus. If you want the focus to revert back to the first JPanel, then you should add an ActionListener to each button, and in the actionPerformed() method of the listener just add the line:

```
firstPanel.requestFocusINnWindow();
```

Comment: Hi @FredK - buttons have ActionListener - I have done that in the same class (JPanel2). I can't call Panel1.requestFocusINnWindow(); from Panel2 though, when there is no instance of it in that class to reference?

Comment: Well that is a design issue in your application. Another reason to use the KeyBindings so you don't have these concerns. Or as a hack you can always pass a reference of panel1 to panel2 when you create the second panel.